# Extend jQuery specified object with custom function

Tags: jquery

With

```
$.fn.customFunction = function(){};
```

we can extend whole jQuery and use it with:

```
$('body').customFunction();
```

Is it possible to extend only specified element like:

```
var elem = $('#elem');
    elem.fn.customFunction = function(){};

elem.customFunction();      // function is called
$('body').customFunction(); // this call should cause error
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the function to be available on that one object? That's easy enough:

```
var elem = $('#elem');
elem.customFunction = function() {};
```

Note that this will only work on that one function. This, for instance, will not work:

```
$('#elem').customFunction();
```

This is because the jQuery constructor makes a new object every time it is run; it does not reuse objects.

Comment: Oh my, I was blinded with `prototype`. Thanks !

Comment: Ok, and if I would like to reuse this function later with creating object again ?\

Comment: The jQuery way would be to have the function exist  on all elements, but only do anything on the one you mean.

Answer (score 5):

```
var elem = $('#elem');
elem.customFunction = function(){};
```

Remove the `fn`.

This can also be used on normal elements (or any other object, for that matter):

```
var elem = document.getElementById('elem')
elem.customFunction = function(){}
```